# Loop across K-uplets from a N-K matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy, python-itertools

I have to use dynamic programming in a python script.

I defined a numpy array u with shape=(N,K).
I want to pick one element for each column, therefore generating a K-uplets.

How would you proceed to loop efficiently across all K-uplets generated this way ? A solution would be to use

```
import itertools
itertools.combination_with_replacement(list,K)
```

where list = [0..N-1], but I will need to build iteratively each of my K-uplets using the output (index) of the itertools method.
Is there a more direct way to proceed ?

Thanks

Vincent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build the K-uplet with `arr[ind, np.arange(K)]`. Of course, that's actually a NumPy ndarray, but they are easy to convert to tuplets if you really want tuplets: `tuple(arr[ind, np.arange(K)])`.

---

```
import numpy as np
import itertools as IT

N, K = 5,3
arr = np.arange(N*K).reshape(N,K)
print(arr)
# [[ 0  1  2]
#  [ 3  4  5]
#  [ 6  7  8]
#  [ 9 10 11]
#  [12 13 14]]

for ind in IT.combinations_with_replacement(range(N), K):
    print(arr[ind, np.arange(K)])
    # [0 1 2]
    # [0 1 5]
    # [0 1 8]
    # [ 0  1 11]
    # ...
```